# Would adding artificial turf to my rooftop patio increase the value of my home?

Tags: real-estate, home

I know there are many ways of increasing the value of home; redoing flooring, replacing old HVAC systems, adding in smart security systems, etc... My house is brand new construction so there isn't much room for improvement, outside of the stuff I have already done (installed NEST thermostats and equipped it with a comprehensive smart ADT security system). I would like to add artificial turf to my rooftop patio because:
1. It would make it more comfortable
2. It would make it look nicer
I am wondering if these opinions are usually ones held by appraisers/the market as well? Would putting artificial turf on the my rooftop patio increase my home's value in the same sure-fire way (not necessarily same magnitude) that alarm systems and conventional upgrades do?

Comment: this might be somewhat subjective... for instance, I would actually not consider a NEST thermostat and ADT security system to be improvements I would pay more for a house for.

Comment: I contest your assertion that **artificial** turf on your rooftop "would make it more comfortable".  (Natural grass, yes, but that's not what your question is about.)

Comment: My read is that you already have a useful roof space, this is a several hundred dollar cosmetic finish  that has maybe 10 years design life under constant UV exposure?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first question about your plan is: are you allowed to? If you live in a community with a home owners association (HOA) or something similar, you may have to go thorough an approval process. If you skip the approval process, they may make you remove it. It can even be discovered just a few days before settlement when the HOA does an inspection.

The second thing to consider is would this plan impact the new house warranty you have. If you mess up the install will they builder still cover their workmanship.

You need to ask local real estate agent. They will know the market. Their concern would be if nobody has this, then maybe it is because nobody wants it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting myself in the shoes of a potential buyer.  I would want to know:

1) Will artificial turf make the underlying patio wet and, for example, promote the growth of mold?

(2) Are there any exposed parts of the patio that might be structurally affected -- i.e. wood that might rot?

Even though you are now certain that you will never want to sell, (a) you could be wrong and (b) these are questions that you should be able to answer looking forward to your own maintenance expenses.